# Reverse Polish converter

Tags: c, reverse, postfix-notation, rpn

I am trying to make a reverse Polish printer which can perform the following operation-

Inputs:

1. `(a+(b*c))`
2. `((a+b)*(z+x))`
3. `((a+t)*((b+(a+c))^(c+d)))`

Outputs:

1. `abc*+`
2. `ab+zx+*`
3. `at+bac++cd+^*`

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char pop(int t);
void push(int c, int t);
int main()
{
    int z;
    scanf("%d", &z);
    char *a[100];
    int i = 0;
    int q = z;
    while (q-- > 0)
    {
        char v[400];
        scanf("%s", &v);
        int t;
        for (t = 0; t < strlen(v); t++)    //loop to put the values and signs in the 2 stacks
        {
            if ((v[t] == '*') || (v[t] == '+') || (v[t] == '-') || (v[t] == '^'))
            {
                push(v[t], 2);


            }

            else if (v[t] == ')')
            {
                int y = pop(2);
                push(y, 1);

            }

            else
            {
                push(v[t], 1);

            }
        }
        int k = 0;
        char c;
        while ((c = pop(1)) !='\0')    //loop to put elements in the array v
        {

            if (c != '(')
            {

                v[k++] = c;

            }
        }
        v[k--] = '\0';
        int m;
        for (m=0; m != k; m++, k--)     //for reversing the string
        {
            char t = v[m];
            v[m] = v[k];
            v[k] = t;
        }

        a[i++] =v;
        printf("%s",a[i - 1]);
    }
    int p;
    for (p = 0; p <z ; p++)   //printing the elements
        printf("%s\n",*a[p]);
    return 0;
}
char ac[400];
char as[400];
int ic = 0;
int is = 0;
void push(int c,int t)
{
    if (t == 1 && ic != 400)
        ac[ic++] = c;
    else if (t == 2 && is != 400)
        as[is++] = c;
}
char pop(int t)
{
    if (t == 1 && ic != 0)
        return ac[--ic];
    if (t == 2 && is != 0)
        return as[--is];
    return '\0';
}
```

But it is not even inputting properly and I am not able to figure out what are the mistakes in this code.Please help to figure out what are the problems.

Comment: What do you mean by "not inputting properly"? What's the input? What's the output? What's the desired output?

Comment: BTW `a[i++] =v;` always last `v`.

Comment: `printf("%s\n",*a[p]);` :  `*a[p]` is `a char`. and `v` is out of scope.

Comment: `for (m=0; m != k; m++, k--)` wrong.

Comment: That 2nd error pointed out by @BLUEPIXY would've been caught by most modern compilers, if warnings were enabled. I **strongly** recommend that you enable warnings (`-Wall` in GCC and CLang; check your compiler's manual if you have some other compiler).

Comment: @Tim Čas From not inputting properly I mean after inputing the no of test cases i.e.int z and first line if input it crashes

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I couldn't understand what you mean by-printf("%s\n",*a[p]); : *a[p] is a char. and v is out of scope.

Comment: `char *a[100];`: `a` is array of pointer to `char`. `a[p]` is pointer to `char`. `*a[p]` pointer dereference is `char`.

Comment: `while (q-- > 0)  {  char v[400];` : `v` is an effective area in the while block. If you see outside of the block is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

> after inputing the no of test cases i.e.int z and first line if input
>   it crashes

This is due to the

```
        printf("%s\n",*a[p]);
```

as BLUEPIXY noticed, *`*a[p]` is a `char`*; but `%s` expects a `char *`, thus you need

```
        printf("%s\n", a[p]);
```

and regarding *`v` is out of scope*, the crucial factor is not the scope (visibility), but the storage duration (lifetime) of `v` - its lifetime ends when execution of the block with which it is associated ends, and the value of a pointer `a[i]` to it becomes indeterminate; by changing

```
        a[i++] =v;
```

to

```
        a[i++] = strdup(v);
```

you can remedy that.